# defining a unique key column in apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to get the distinct records from a table, as many duplicate rows are coming from the following query

```
select * from sales_details_view;
```

When I query the following query in pl/sql developer, I am getting correct results

```
select distinct * from sales_details_view;
```

But when I use the same query in an interactive report in Oracle APEX 4.1, it is giving me the following error

> The report query needs a unique key to identify each row. The supplied
>   key cannot be used for this query. Please edit the report attributes
>   to define a unique key column. ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or
>   sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set **Link Column** (in **Report Attributes**) to something other than "Link to Single Row View". You can set it to either "Exclude Link Column" or "Link to Custom Target".